# Optimize SQL Query on calculated value?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a query that requires a where statement on a calculated value:

```
select * from table where date( timestamp ) = ?
```

An explain on this query yields the expected ALL select type, which is not ideal.  Using MySQL, what's the best way to optimize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option might be to rewrite the query such that the calculations are all done on the other side of the equation. For example:

```
timestamp >= <some date> AND timestamp < <some date + 1>
```

In this query, "some date" would be midnight of that date.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where  timestamp  = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('?');
```